# Dog running after shepherd

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

Assume there is a dog `A` on a field and a sephard `B`. `B` moves on straight line with constant $v$ velocity. The dog `A` is running always towards `B` with also constant - magnitude  `$u$ velocity.

If initially `B`'s velocity vector is perpendicular to `A`'s velocity vector, when will they meet?

Is it possible to solve the problem above without the use of calculus? How?

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve), [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html), and [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=pursuit+curve).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected there would be a lot of questions like this, I just didn't know the term _pursuit_ _curve_ before. Unfortunately all the answers/solutions I've checked so far involved higher mathematics, and I suspect there is an easier solution in this special case, that is what I want to find.

Comment: Your problem is completely solved in [Radiodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome), with $V_t=v$, $V_d=u$ and $y'(0)=0$. If the initial distance in the *x* direction between dog and shepherd is *a*, the dog will catch the shepherd after he has walked a distance  ${auv\over u^2-v^2}$ on the *y*axis. The simplicity of the answer might suggest a simpler, geometrical, non-calculus solution, perhaps.