# 2d particle collision, Time for one particle to catch another one

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

[image: Initial physical situation]

Say we have 2 particles where 1 moves with constant velocity $u$ and the other moves with speed $v$ towards the first particle. After what time does the 2nd particle catches up with the 1st one?

Comment: Well, that is how we got the assignment and there is a solution, this is just the initial situation, v changes direction

Comment: I do notice $|v|=const$ now, as opposed to $v=const$, so my previous comment is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, v is always towards the particle moving upwards

Comment: Though....it might also depend on the relation between $u$ and $v$. For instance, suppose $u=1000$ m/s and $v=3$ m/s, the 2nd object will never catch up with the first. Or, if $v=1000$ m/s and $u=3$ m/s, then it'd happen pretty quickly. Does your instructor give any relation between the two?

Comment: So, I broke v into its horizontal and vertical component v[x] and v[y] and using the average velocities (v[avg]= x[total]/t[total]) stated that (delta)t = s/u = l/v[x,avg] = s/v[y,avg] where s is the path that the 1st particle will cross and l is the initial distance between the particles, then by substituting s got that (delta)t = (l*v[y,avg])/(u*v[x,avg]) continuation follows

Comment: No, he doesnt't

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77920/2451 See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve), [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html), and [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=pursuit+curve).